# create YouTube video slideshow from image and audio inputs

Tags: grails, audio, video, youtube

I'd like to upload an audio file to my website, programmatically create an video slideshow using an image already on the server, and then upload that video to YouTube using its API. The website is built on Grails, so a Java solution would be great; Linux command line could also work.

Uploading videos using the YouTube API is working well. I also have no trouble getting avconv or ffmpeg to create videos that will play in, for example, Windows Media Player. This works to make a playable movie:

avconv -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 video.mpg

However, manually uploading that video to YouTube results in a format error. I can create other files that YouTube will process successfully, but the audio plays back with regular stutters. (A second or so of clear audio, then a brief gap, then some clear audio, ...) For example:

avconv -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 video.mkv

I have experimented with a variety of output formats and codecs, but all fall into one of those categories: apparent encoding success but YouTube processing failure, or processing success but unacceptable audio playback.

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'm open to any solution that will let me solve the basic problem of uploading audio to YouTube via my Grails website without forcing my users to create the video slideshow themselves.

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Comment: Animoto (http://animoto.com/) is the closest thing I've found yet. I'm looking also, and haven't found the right tool yet. Animoto provides a solid API as well as a Ruby gem to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to create a YouTube slideshow video on iPad. [This guide](http://slideshow-studio.com/slideshow/create-video-upload-youtube-ipad/) shows the steps.

Adding music, applying transitions, editing photos can all be done there.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question. There are many ways for me as a user to create such a file manually. The goal is to automate the creation of such files in a running webapp.

Answer (score -1):

I built a pretty similar web service, based on [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org): it's called `tovid.io` — uploads user-provided mp3 to YouTube as a video, using uploaded image file for a visual track. User uploads mp3 file, an image, then we render a video in the backend, and publish it on YouTube under the user's account.

It is very easy to render an h264 mp4 video following [YouTube specs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) using Linux command line ffmpeg. Let me know if you're interested in our particular command line.